# Binding to a click event to find a child elements input value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

here is my jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/YJqAu/

When the user clicks on the toggle, I'd like to know the current value of the input field. You can see from the logs that jQuery is not sending back the input field value. Why is that? Ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
alert($('input', $(this)).val()); // echoed out 'on' for me
```

Answer (score 0):

The input has no value, it is a checkbox. To get whether or not the checkbox is checked you can use `$(this).is(":checked")`.